# @'Event$variable' iphone Object C

Tags: iphone, variables

$variable  =1;

How i can do it? 
I need insert variable 1 2 3 4 5 ...
in @"Event" or @'Event'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stabbing in the dark here, but is this what you want?

```
int variable = 1;

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event%d", variable];
```